# AngularJS show video after inactivity, hide video and reset to beginning on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, video

I am attempting to make a sort of screensaver using AngularJS. What I would like is to have a video pop up and start playing after a specified number of seconds after the user stops interacting with the page(not moving their mouse or clicking). Then once the video is playing, if the user clicks on the video, I want the video to pause, reset to 0:00 and then hide as well as reset the inactivity timer so that it shows and starts playing after another x number of seconds of inactivity.

I am very new to AngularJS, but here is what I have come up with so far based on my knowledge of Javascript:

```js
(function(){
    
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    
    myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $timeout){
        
        $scope.videoVisible = false;
        
        var video = $('#video1')[0];
        
        //5 second delay
        $timeout( function(){
            $scope.videoVisible = true;
            video.currentTime = 0;
            video.load();
        }, 5000 );

        $scope.hideVideo = function() {
          $scope.videoVisible = false;
          video.pause();
          video.currentTime = 0;
        }
        
        // This part should reset the timeout if the user is moving their mouse or clicking
        $(document.body).bind('mousemove keydown click', RESETTIMER);
        
    });
    
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <div ng-show="videoVisible" ng-click="hideVideo()">
          <video id="video1" style="width:600px;max-width:100%;" controls="">
            <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
            Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
          </video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had already made a similar functionality for another SO question.

<kbd>**SO Answer**</kbd>

I have modified it based on your requirements. Basically there are two functions you need to modify.

`$scope.pause` -  which will pause the video, when the user has any activity.

`$scope.play` - Which will play the video when the user is inactive (for the below example, the time of inactivity is set to 5 seconds)

`$scope.hide` - Which hides the video player when the user has clicked on the paused video.

The most important function is.

```
monitorTimeout($scope.pause, 1000, 5000);
```

In the above function `$scope.pause` (1st parameter) defines the function that will run on each iteration. The `1000` (2nd parameter) signifies the number of times the first parameter is run. The final parameter signifies the timeout for the user inactivity (here it is 5 seconds), after which `$scope.play` is run.

**Snippet**

```js
var myModule = angular.module('myApp', []);
myModule.controller("TextController", function($scope, $interval, $document, $timeout) {

  $scope.videoVisible = false;
  var video = $('#video1')[0];

  $scope.hideVideo = function() {
    $scope.videoVisible = false;
  }
  //function to call
  $scope.pause = function() {
    video.pause();
    video.currentTime = 0;
    console.log("user active");
  };

  $scope.play = function() {
    $scope.videoVisible = true;
    video.currentTime = 0;
    video.load();
    video.play();
    console.log("user inActive");
  }

  //main function
  //functionName - specify the function that needs to be repeated for the intervalTime
  //intervalTime - the value is in milliseconds, the functionName is continuously repeated for this time.
  //timeoutValue - the value is in milliseconds, when this value is exceeded the function given in functionName is stopped

  monitorTimeout($scope.pause, 1000, 5000);

  function monitorTimeout(functionName, intervalTime, timeoutValue) {
    //initialization parameters
    timeoutValue = timeoutValue || 5000;
    intervalTime = intervalTime || 1000;
    // Start a timeout
    var TimeOut_Thread = $timeout(function() {
      TimerExpired()
    }, timeoutValue);
    var bodyElement = angular.element($document);

    /// Keyboard Events
    bodyElement.bind('keydown', function(e) {
      TimeOut_Resetter(e)
    });
    bodyElement.bind('keyup', function(e) {
      TimeOut_Resetter(e)
    });

    /// Mouse Events    
    bodyElement.bind('click', function(e) {
      TimeOut_Resetter(e)
    });
    bodyElement.bind('mousemove', function(e) {
      TimeOut_Resetter(e)
    });
    bodyElement.bind('DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
      TimeOut_Resetter(e)
    });
    bodyElement.bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
      TimeOut_Resetter(e)
    });
    bodyElement.bind('mousedown', function(e) {
      TimeOut_Resetter(e)
    });

    /// Touch Events
    bodyElement.bind('touchstart', function(e) {
      TimeOut_Resetter(e)
    });
    bodyElement.bind('touchmove', function(e) {
      TimeOut_Resetter(e)
    });

    /// Common Events
    bodyElement.bind('scroll', function(e) {
      TimeOut_Resetter(e)
    });
    bodyElement.bind('focus', function(e) {
      TimeOut_Resetter(e)
    });

    function TimerExpired() {
      if (theInterval) {
        $scope.play();
        $interval.cancel(theInterval);
        theInterval = undefined;
      }
    }

    function TimeOut_Resetter(e) {
      if (!theInterval) {
        theInterval = $interval(function() {
          functionName();
        }.bind(this), intervalTime);
      }

      /// Stop the pending timeout
      $timeout.cancel(TimeOut_Thread);

      /// Reset the timeout
      TimeOut_Thread = $timeout(function() {
        TimerExpired()
      }, timeoutValue);
    }

    var theInterval = $interval(function() {
      functionName();
    }.bind(this), intervalTime);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="TextController">
    <div ng-show="videoVisible" ng-click="hideVideo()">
      <video id="video1" style="width:600px;max-width:100%;" controls="">
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg"> Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
      </video>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```